# Test output of function that have For loop using robot-framework

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I have function that have For loop and return for each iteration True or False

```
def testcase(x,testType=""):
        parameter_list = open("Parameter_List.csv")
        Parameters = csv.reader(parameter_list)
        if x =='compagne' :
            for row in Parameters :
                param = row[0].split(";")
                if param == ["Name","Format","Arraysize","MinVal","MaxVal","Default Val"] :
                    pass
                else :
                    parameter = Parameter(param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4], param[5])
                    return parameter.robotALLtest()
    
        elif x == 'one test' and testType in ["Min Value", "Max Value", "Lower Min", "Greater Max", "Persistence ON", "Persistence OFF", "Rset"] :
            for row in Parameters:
                param = row[0].split(";")
                if param == ["Name", "Format", "Arraysize", "MinVal", "MaxVal", "Default Val"]:
                    pass
                else:
                    parameter = Parameter(
                    param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4], param[5])
                    return parameter.robotTestParameter(testType)
        else :
            for row in Parameters:
                param = row[0].split(";")
                if x == param[0] :
                    parameter = Parameter(param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4], param[5])
                    break
            return parameter.robotTestParameter(testType)
```

I used RobotFreamwork to test the output

```
*** Settings ***
Library  test_cases.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test Parameter
    
    ${value}  test_cases.testcase   ${'one test'}   ${'Lower Min'}
    SHOULD BE EQUAL     ${value}    ${True}
```

But i have just the result for the first iteration.
What can i do to get all the results?

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave:

```py
        elif x == 'one test' and testType in ["Min Value", "Max Value", "Lower Min", "Greater Max", "Persistence ON", "Persistence OFF", "Rset"] :
            for row in Parameters:
                param = row[0].split(";")
                if param == ["Name", "Format", "Arraysize", "MinVal", "MaxVal", "Default Val"]:
                    pass
                else:
                    parameter = Parameter(
                    param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4], param[5])
                    return parameter.robotTestParameter(testType)
```

your code looks like "lets read this csv file, if the row looks like a header, lets skip that but if its actual test data, it goes to the else branch.

And that else branch will `return parameter.robotTestParameter(testType)`  from the `testcase()`, thus, you only loop 2 rows from the Parameters and first non-header row is the only that is applied.

So, essentially, your code works exactly how you wrote it.

On python side, you could do something like

```py
result = True
for row in Parameters:
   param = row[0].split(";")
   if param == ["Name", "Format", "Arraysize", "MinVal", "MaxVal", "Default Val"]:
       pass
   else:
       parameter = Parameter(
       param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4], param[5])
       if parameter.robotTestParameter(testType) == False:
           result = False
return result
```

*BUT* this is not very good approach to solve the situation .. I'd start looking and learning on how to use Datadriver library / https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver

Comment: i think you don't understand me , for each row the script return True or False i have more than 100 rows i want to test the result from looping all the rows for example : row 1 i have parameter 1 , parameter.robotTestParameter(testType) return True or False then row 2 parameter 2 ,  parameter.robotTestParameter(testType) return True or False then all the parameters in the csv file. i want to have general test review to all the test

Comment: Either you dont understand what i tried to say or you where not very clear about the issue and my assumption was wrong.  For the first part:  because you call return from inside the for loop, you do not have a *loop*, you just run the testcase against the first non-header in the csv file.  If this is not the case, then the issue is in your `Parameter` class. Maybe you could share how the Parameter_list.csv looks like ?

Comment: When i run the script and print(parameter.robotTestParameter(testType)) the script is running well and i have for each row the returned value from parameter.robotTestParameter(testType) which is could be True or False so i don't have a problem in the code. my problem is how to how to impliment that in robot freamwork , i want to test each returned value and get general report of test ,  if the returned value = True the test get  the status passed and if returned value = False the test get the status failed. i hope that is clear.